# How to Export sharepoint 2010 SPGridView data to excel

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, export-to-excel, spgridview

How to Export sharepoint 2010 SPGridView data to excel.

My SPGridView contains Expand/Collapse section also. So i need to get all spgridview value to export to excel. Give me some nice approach to start this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this post - http://www.fivenumber.com/export-spgridview-to-excel-spreadsheet-in-sharepoint-2007/

Comment: doing the same but i need to add some formate in excel cell like border, bgcolor. how to do that?\

Comment: I that possible to get the expand collapse thing into excel